# How to move a window from one screen to another and maximise in one go?

Tags: macos, catalina

I am trying to accomplish the above-mentioned. Move a window from one screen to another and maximise it in one step, without creating a new virtual screen.

Has anyone found a way to accomplish this on the most recent version of MacOS?

Comment: You can move from one screen to another and do a full-screen in one go. If that works for you.

Comment: And how do you do that?

Comment: How about this: https://i.imgur.com/Y5wlMYC.mp4 ?

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, meant to move to an existing screen, not create a new virtual one.

Answer (score 1):

As OP themselves commented, this popup helped them:

[image]

---

> without creating a new virtual screen.

That is an invalid requirement. Fullscreen apps make a space of their own.

I think your requirement is to make an fullscreen next to where it is, instead of going to the far right.

- Hold the green button on the top left.
- Click somewhere in the same window.

Comment: I believe I found it! https://i.imgur.com/nVWj0Gz.png Thanks!

Comment: oh, that's new on Catalina. Please post a new answer (:

Answer (score 1):

I use `Mission Control` for this on macOS 10.15 (Catalina):

1. Start `Mission Control` from the Launchpad, OR using the *gesture* defined in `System Preferences -> Trackpad -> More gestures`, OR using the shortcut defined in `System Preferences -> Mission Control`.
2. Once `Mission Control` is started, you'll see all of your desktops at the top of your display - let's call this area of the display a "ribbon".
3. On your current desktop, select the app you want to make fullscreen, and drag it into the "ribbon" at the top of the screen. The "ribbon" should now be displaying thumbnails of your desktops - instead of the text label "`Desktop 1` `Desktop 2`  etc" . **DO NOT RELEASE** the selected app yet.
4. Finally, drag/position the selected app such that it is **between** two of the desktop thumbnails in the "ribbon". Release the app. The app is now full screen, and located between the two desktops.